# Method is being read as attribute?

Tags: python

I can't use any of the methods in this class. Every time I try, I get an error that doesn't make sense.

```
Walker(cube)

c.move()

Error: Walker instance has no attribute 'move'
```

Here's the code:

```
import pymel.core as pm

import random

class Walker(object):

    def __init__(self, cube):
        self.cube = cube
        self.tx = 0
        self.ty = 0
        self.tz = 0


    def move(self):

        step_dict = {0: move_x, 1: move_y, 2: move_z}
        step = random.randint(0,2)
        self.step_dict[step]()

    def move_x(self):
        step_dict = {0: 1, 1: -1}
        step = random.randint(0,1)
        attr_value = selt.tx + step_dict[step]
        pm.setAttr('%s.translateX' % (self.cube), attr_value)
        self.tx = attr_value

    def move_y(self):
        step_dict = {0: 1, 1: -1}
        step = random.randint(0,1)
        attr_value = selt.ty + step_dict[step]
        pm.setAttr('%s.translateY' % (self.cube), attr_value)
        self.ty = attr_value

    def move_z(self):
        step_dict = {0: 1, 1: -1}
        step = random.randint(0,1)
        attr_value = selt.tz + step_dict[step]
        pm.setAttr('%s.translateZ' % (self.cube), attr_value)
        self.tz = attr_value
```

Comment: user3286261, what did you use to run it?

Comment: c = Walker(27); c.move()

Comment: If def move() is not indented, I get your attribute error.

Comment: figured it out my code editor kept adding levels of indentation that I could not see while editing (somehow). Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Smart money is `c` is not an instance of `Walker`.  Try this:

```
 type(c)
```

It's supposed to say

```
<class '__main__.Walker'>
```

Comment: hey Malvolio, it's definitely an instance, cause i can access tx, ty, tz, and cube just can't use the methods.

Comment: Is this in a file, or are you typing it into the interpreter?  Because I think Dan is right, or at least on the right track.  For some reason, the class definition is ending after the init.  Try removing some of the superfluous newlines and double-check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Class methods have to be part of the class block.

This gives "'Walker' object has no attribute 'move'" because move() is not a class method. "def move.." has to be indent to the same level as **init**.

```
class Walker(object):

    def __init__(self, cube):
        self.cube = cube
        self.tx = 0
        self.ty = 0
        self.tz = 0

def move(self):
    print('hi')
    step_dict = {0: self.move_x(), 1: self.move_y(), 2: self.move_z()}
    step = random.randint(0,2)
    self.step_dict[step]()

c = Walker(27)
c.move()
```

The following works because the indentation makes move() part of the class block:

```
class Walker(object):

    def __init__(self, cube):
        self.cube = cube
        self.tx = 0
        self.ty = 0
        self.tz = 0

    def move(self):
        print('hi')
        step_dict = {0: self.move_x(), 1: self.move_y(), 2: self.move_z()}
        step = random.randint(0,2)
        self.step_dict[step]()

c = Walker(27)
c.move()
```